# How to move to previous Row in DataGridView using Button Click?

Tags: button, datagridview, click

I am trying to move to previous row in DataGridView using a button click. On first click it moves to previous row but on second click it stucks on the the same row. Can anybody help ?

```
Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click
    Dim i As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index - 1

    TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value
    TextBox2.Text = DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value

    DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Selected = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `CurrentCell` in order to change `CurrentRow` property which is read-only.

```
Dim i As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index - 1

TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value
TextBox2.Text = DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value

Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0)
Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Selected = True
```